# How to import files from 3rd party into Angular 2 Typescript project?

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

I have an Angular 2 project with components that we bring on build into another project written in angular 1. The problem is the files are like 3rd party, we don't want any one to commit them only use them. The files are enter the "target" folder, but in `App.Module.ts` I can't set import to that folder. Any idea how to do that correctly?

What I don't understnad is how we can use componenet that written somewhere else if we must declare it in 'app.module.ts' files in order to use it in the project.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { UpgradeModule } from '@angular/upgrade/static';

import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

/* HelloWorldComponent is a 3th party, its files are inside target folder,
so how to import it? */
/* import { HelloWorldComponent } from './app/hello-world.component';*/


@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        HelloWorldComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        UpgradeModule
    ],
    exports: [
        HelloWorldComponent
    ],
    entryComponents: [
        HelloWorldComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: []
})

export class AppModule {
    ngDoBootstrap() {}
}


import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(platformRef => {
    const upgrade = platformRef.injector.get(UpgradeModule) as UpgradeModule;
    upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, ['myApp']);
    ;})


import * as _angular_ from 'angular';

declare global {
    const angular: typeof _angular_;
}

import { downgradeComponent } from '@angular/upgrade/static';

angular.module('myApp')
    .directive(
        'helloWorld',
        downgradeComponent({component: HelloWorldComponent}) as angular.IDirectiveFactory
    );
```

Comment: Can you give more context, please? Are you trying to dynamically import files on runtime?

Comment: added more info to the problem

Comment: So, if this is the relative path to your 3rd party file. Where is the problem? Are errors thrown?

Comment: I can't get the relative path to work for some reason

Comment: Please post your error message. It is not possible to help you with out it.

Comment: Error:(19, 36) TS2307:Cannot find module '../../../.././target/home/framework/dev/components/src/app/hello-world/hello-world.component'.

Comment: I did got the currect relative URL, but onload I get systemJS error: systemjs.import error: Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading

Comment: So (1) you're path is wrong or (2) the file has no export statement or (3) the file doesn't exist at the path at compile time.

Comment: export exists. I see there is a problem with the URL in compile time. there is one folder path that should be removed, but without it the app.module.ts will not find it at all. like they look diffrently on the files tree